# Visual Studio: how to make auto namespace import with light bulb fully qualified?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Light bulb generates `using Pipeline.ResultStorage;` instead of `MyCompany.MyProject.Pipeline.ResultStorage;`. Is there a way to make it generating full namespace?

`using Pipeline.ResultStorage;` works, because it is sub namespace of this assembly, but standards in my team require full namespace.

Comment: Is Pipeline.ResultStorage namespace in a dependency package you are extending into your own project?

Comment: Or is it just a sub namespace of your own project at it's importing them using relative paths?